# Coefficient of variation in a gamma location-scale mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, gamma-distribution, ecology, coefficient-of-variation

In ecology, location-scale mixed models are often used to extract the so-called 'coefficient of individual variation for predictability' (e.g. see, for instance, [this paper](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.12281)), which is defined as the coefficient of variation for the cluster-varying intercept parameters in the model for the scale of the distribution. Imagine we have a model describing some trait $y$ measured at instance $i$ and individual $j$:

\begin{equation}
   y_{ij} \sim Normal(\mu_{ij}, \sigma_{ij})
\end{equation}

where the model of the location is:

\begin{equation}
   \mu_{ij} = \alpha + \nu_{1j}
\end{equation}

and the model of the scale (standard deviation) is:

\begin{equation}
   \log(\sigma_{ij}) = \zeta + \nu_{2j}
\end{equation}

where for simplicity we assume that the individual-level terms are independent:

\begin{equation}
   \nu_{1j} = Normal(0, \sigma_{v1})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \nu_{2j} = Normal(0, \sigma_{\nu2})
\end{equation}

From this model, the coefficient of variation for predictability is defined from the [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) as:

\begin{equation}
   CV_{p} = \sqrt{ e^{\sigma_{\nu2}^2} - 1 }
\end{equation}

Recently, I have been working with the same model but with a Gamma likelihood, where the Gamma distribution is parameterized using shape and rate parameters $\kappa$ and $\theta$, respectively, which relate to the location $\eta$ and scale (standard deviation) $\phi$ of the Gamma as:

\begin{equation}
   \kappa = \eta^2 / \phi^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \theta = \kappa / \eta
\end{equation}

Now, the location and scale models above both use the log-link function:

\begin{equation}
   \log(\eta_{ij}) = \alpha + \nu_{1j}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \log(\phi_{ij}) = \zeta + \nu_{2j}
\end{equation}

In the Gamma distribution, the variance is a function of the mean, i.e. $\phi^2 = \frac{\kappa}{\theta^2} = \frac{\eta}{\theta}$, which makes it [more difficult to calculate residual variances for variance components analyses](https://www.rdatagen.net/post/icc-for-gamma-distribution/) and requires approximations, such as the [trigamma function](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/early/2016/12/21/095851.full.pdf), where $\text{trigamma}(\kappa_{ij})$ would provide the residual variance for each individual at each measurement instance.

Because of this, I think it's also non-trivial to calculate the coefficient of predictability for a Gamma likelihood model. Does anyone know the exact relationship?

My own attempt is that the coefficient of variation of the Gamma is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\kappa}}$, which can be calculated for the population averages from the above model as:

\begin{equation}
   CV_{gamma} = \frac{\exp(\zeta) }{ \exp(\alpha) }
\end{equation}

Thus, would replacing the population-average scale, $\exp(\zeta)$, with the standard deviation of group-level standard deviations, $\sigma_{\nu2}$, also work to represent the coefficient of predictability?